# SQL query to determine if a JSON value contains a specified attribute

Tags: mysql, json, attributes

I have a table with a column for storing a JSON value for each row. Currently, these are not standardized. I'd like to end up with each of these JSON values being standardized in number and title of attributes. Is there a query I can use to determine whether or not each JSON value contains a specified attribute?

As an example, here are what some of the JSON values look like:

```
{"name":"Item 1","cost":"4.99"}
{"name":"Item 2"}
{"name":"Item 3","cost":""}
{"name":"Item 4"}
```

How do I:

- Determine which rows *have* a "cost" attribute (items 1 & 3)
- Determine which rows do not have a "cost" attribute (items 2 & 4)
- Determine which rows have a value set for the "cost" attribute (item 1)

Thank you! This is my first time asking (at least recently) so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Parse the string value of the field looking for a `cost` attribute.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

I assume you're using MySQL 5.7, which adds the `JSON` data type. Use [`JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$.cost')`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) to access the `cost` property. It will be `NULL` is there's no such property.

1. `WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$.cost') IS NOT NULL`
2. `WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$.cost') IS NULL`
3. `WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$.cost') != ''`

It will also be `NULL` if the value in the JSON is `null`; if you need to distinguish this case, see [Can't detect null value from JSON_EXTRACT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171636/cant-detect-null-value-from-json-extract/41172432#41172432)

Comment: Bummer that I can't differentiate between the attribute not being there vs. the attribute being there, but with no value. Still, this is pretty close and will help me greatly. Thanks!

Comment: Do you every have `"cost": null` in your JSON data?

Comment: Some of the rows have a "cost" attribute, but not all. My goal was to try and quickly sort out the rows that didn't have it, so I could add one in, then go through with a JSON modify function to update just that piece, rather than updating the JSON string as a whole.

Comment: That should work. The only thing you can't distinguish is no cost attribute from `"cost": null`. `"cost": ""` is still distinguishable.

Comment: Your answer is actually accurate. MySQL does distinguish the SQL `NULL` from JSON's `null`. You could remove the last statement. Refer to this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172432/1128918

Comment: I've replaced it with a link to that question, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

If you need to only check, whether the json key exists, you can use JSON_CONTAINS_PATH. I expect it to be faster than JSON_EXTRACT.

[mySQL 8.0 docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html)

*Example:*

I have a permission column in the DB. The structure looks like this:

```
{
    "users": {
        "user1" : "rw",
        "user2" : "r"
    },
    "groups": {
        "root": "rw",
        "anotherGroup" : "r"
    }
}
```

If I want to get all the items, that have the root group (regarding of the actual permissions), I use this:

```
SELECT * FROM `filesystem_folders` where JSON_CONTAINS_PATH(permissions, 'one', '$.groups.root');
```

I made just a very simple time comparison between the *select* above which took **12.90s** (10000 reads). Vs the following select using *JSON_EXTRACT*

```
 SELECT * FROM `filesystem_folders` where JSON_EXTRACT(permissions, '$.groups.root') IS NOT NULL;
```

which took **15.13s**. So, quite a small difference.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can do it by comparing the `JSON_EXTRACT` result to itself:

```
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$."cost"') = JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$."cost"')
```

This is going to be somehow "false" / null, if there is no corresponding key inside your JSON column.

This way you are able to find all entries that have the key you search for. If you want all the entries that dont have the key you somehow can't use the NOT operator. You have to do it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM tablename WHERE WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$."cost"') = JSON_EXTRACT(colname, '$."cost"'))
```

I know it looks like voodoo, but it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a MySQL without JSON functions (pre 5.7), or want to check for any tag in lists of, or unpredictably nested JSON.

Here is an example of how to do it with `LIKE`:

```
SELECT case when colname like '%cost%' then 1 else 0 end as has_cost,
       case when colname like '%cost":""%' then 1 else 0 end as has_cost_with_no_value
FROM tablename
```

Comment: MySQL supports JSON queries, this is way, way overboard for what you need to do. See other answers.

Comment: This a very dirty way and not right at all. MySQL provides native functionality (see other posts) to resolve JSON tasks

Comment: Pre version 5.7? As far as i am aware JSON support was first implemented in 5.7