# Right way to select not empty values in a json column with Laravel > 5.6?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5.7

I can't seem to able to wrap my head around this.

I got several translations in a json column called `text`, and I want to select only those records that have not empty translations for a specific language (not set, or not `null`).

I struggle in creating a query that doesn't return a record if the value is set to `null`.
Here are some `text` column json values, and I need a query that returns only the first record in this example, where I have a translation for the `fr` value:

```
text: "{"de": "danke", "fr": "merci"}"
text: "{"de": "hallo", "fr": null}"
text: "{"de": "und"}"
```

Here is what I tried so far:

```
parent::whereRaw( 'JSON_EXTRACT(text, "$.fr") is not null' )->get();
```

-> returns

```
text: "{"de": "danke", "fr": "merci"}"
text: "{"de": "hallo", "fr": null}"
```

Bummer. It skips the record where `fr` is not set at all (that's ok), but keeps selecting the record where `fr` is set to `null`. So, I need to adjust the query to exclude the record with `"fr": null`

Let's approach this step by step. When I try a positive match search for a string like this:

```
parent::whereRaw( 'JSON_EXTRACT(text, "$.fr") = "merci"' )->get();
```

-> returns

```
text: "{"de": "danke", "fr": "merci"}"
```

That is correct. Now, it would seem easy to find a way to switch this around and exclude records with `"fr": null`. But no luck.

```
parent::whereRaw( 'JSON_EXTRACT(text, "$.fr") <> "merci"' )->get();
```

-> returns **only** the record where `fr` is set, but is not equal to `merci`. It skips the record where `fr` is not set.

```
text: "{"de": "hallo", "fr": null}"
```

Let's try to exclude records where fr is set to null. But no luck either:

```
parent::whereRaw( 'JSON_EXTRACT(text, "$.fr") <> "null"' )->get();
```

-> returns

```
text: "{"de": "danke", "fr": "merci"}"
text: "{"de": "hallo", "fr": null}"
```

Or,

```
parent::whereRaw( 'JSON_EXTRACT(text, "$.fr") <> null' )->get();
```

-> returns an empty result.

How the heck can I exclude `fr` values that are not set or are set to `null`?

Comment: this is not an answer but, if you're using laravel you may want to use laravel localization https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/localization

Comment: @HasanTıngır: I am using the spatie/laravel-translatable package and I need to filter the translations.

Comment: using that serialize, unserialize methods in each query, slow down your application. I think creating trans table way much better, faster and easy to handle. https://imgur.com/a/EsdpBEh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution in a similar [Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41172432/4688612). It is not a very obvious issue I would say for someone with beginner knowledge.

It seems that the `null` value in the json column doesn't evaluate to the same `null` value in my previous query attempts. It needs to be adjusted as follows, and then it works. Basically the null value needs first to be changed to the same `null` value type with the following code:

```
CAST("null" AS JSON)
```

And then fit it into the query:

```
parent::whereRaw( 'JSON_EXTRACT(text, "$.fr") <> CAST("null" AS JSON)' )->get();
```

Comment: hi how can i put OR condition where not NULL or '' (empty string)
i ahve tried <> CAST("null" AS JSON), <> CAST("''" AS JSON) but its not working..

i want to return values that are not null or empty string inside of  json part. It is possible? Im confused also on the stackoverlfow thread how to do it