# MySQL JSON_EXTRACT subquery not working when enclosed in IFNULL

Tags: mysql, json

**Goal**
Select a value based on a value returned by a subquery that is using JSON_EXTRACT which either returns a 'value' or NULL. IFNULL should be able to allow you to set a default value when the JSON_EXTRACT does not return a result.

**Problem**
When using a subquery that uses JSON_EXTRACT and returns a result, will return nothing when enclosed in IFNULL ignoring the default value.

**Consider the following case**
We want to select a **SubscriptionPlan.name** based on an identifier that is the result of a subquery using JSON_EXTRACT.

```sql
SELECT 
    subscriptionplan.name
FROM
    SubscriptionPlan AS subscriptionplan
WHERE
    subscriptionplan.identifier = (
                        SELECT 
                            JSON_EXTRACT(product.data, '$.identifier')
                        FROM
                            Subscription AS subscription
                        JOIN
                            Product AS product ON product.productid = subscription.productid
                        WHERE
                            subscription.status = 'ACTIVE'
                        AND
                            subscription.ownerid = :userId
                    )
```

**Case 1. SUCCESS without IFNULL**

```
Subscription exists with status 'ACTIVE' and 'userId'
- Subquery result: 'PRO' and thus finds the SubscriptionPlan
- Final result: 'Professional'
```

**Case 2. NOT FOUND without IFNULL**

```
Subscription not found with status 'ACTIVE' and 'userId'
- Subquery result: NULL and thus does not find a SubscriptionPlan
- Final result: NULL
```

Now we add the **IFNULL** operation to default to 'FREE' subscription plan:

```sql
subscriptionplan.identifier = IFNULL(
                                  ( SELECT JSON_EXTRACT ... ),
                                  'FREE'
                              )
```

**Case 3. SUCCESS with IFNULL**

```
Subscription exists with status 'ACTIVE' and 'userId'
 - Subquery result: NULL even though the subscription was found !???
 - Final result: NULL
```

**Case 4. NOT FOUND with IFNULL**

```
Subscription not found with status 'ACTIVE' and 'userId'
 - Subquery result: FREE and thus finds the FREE SubscriptionPlan
 - Final result: 'Free'
```

The **IFNULL** expression nullifies the subquery result, and it does not default to 'FREE'.

My thoughts are as follows:

- Case 4: is using the IFNULL default value string 'FREE' and therefore works as intended
- Case 3: subquery should return PRO and even if it returns NULL, it should default to 'FREE', neither happens
- Maybe adding the IFNULL query adds another nesting layer where

What i've tried and did not work:

- IF( () IS NULL, 'do stuff', 'do other stuff')
- IF( ISNULL(<query<), 'do stuff', 'do other stuff')
- IF( () = null , ..., ...)
- IF( () = NULL , ..., ...)
- IF( () = 'null' , ..., ...)
- IF( () = 'NULL' , ..., ...)

Also according to [Can't detect null value from JSON_EXTRACT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41171636/cant-detect-null-value-from-json-extract):

- IF ( JSON_EXTRACT(product.data, '$.identifier') = CAST('null' AS JSON), ...., ... )

All failures! Why is JSON_EXTRACT subquery not working when enclosed in IFNULL?

Comment: You need to use `json_value` or `->>`  as you already figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've found out what caused the error.

JSON_EXTRACT adds quotes around its result resulting in "PRO" instead of PRO and therefore the IFNULL default is not triggered and the subscription plan, which is PRO, is not found using "PRO".

Add JSON_UNQUOTE around the JSON_EXTRACT solves the issue.

Comment: `product.data->>'$.identifier'` is more simple than ```JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(product.data, '$.identifier'))```

Comment: *Select a value based on a value returned by a subquery that is using JSON_EXTRACT which either returns a 'value' or NULL.* It seems that you confuse SQL `NULL` and JSON `null` which are NOT the same.

Comment: also because a JSON `null` value is not a SQL `NULL`, you probably want to wrap the `->>` call in a `NULLIF` - ie. `IFNULL(NULLIF(product.data->>'$.identifier','null'),'FREE')`