# MySQL JSON_REPLACE - if key does not exist create key

Tags: mysql

I am using `JSON_REPLACE` to update the value of a key, but I am having a hard time figure out how to create the key before updating it if it does not exist.

This is how my query looks like.

```
$query_update = "UPDATE `forms` SET `conf` = JSON_REPLACE(`conf`, '$.title', '$title') WHERE id='32'";
```

Any idea how can I do that in the same query?

**UPDATE**
Thanks to the comments by Juan Eizmendi and Salman A below, changing `JSON_REPLACE` to `JSON_SET` resolved the problem.

**The updated query looks like that**

```
$query_update = "UPDATE `forms` SET `conf` = JSON_SET(`conf`, '$.title', '$title') WHERE id='32'";
```

Comment: you can use [JSON_SET](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set)  (inserts or updates).

Comment: Sure, but how can I check if the key exists in the same query?

Comment: So you want to update the key if exists, if it doesn't create _key/value_ pair, that's what `JSON_SET` does. if you only want to check for a key [determine if a json value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731954/sql-query-to-determine-if-a-json-value-contains-a-specified-attribute/39732861)

Comment: Yes, I want to first check if the pair exist and if yes update, else create. But don't know how to combine both `JSON_REPLACE` and `JSON_SET`

Comment: @SalmanA, Of course, I can run a separate select to check if exists and create if not. My quesation is how to do it in the same query. how to combine both `JSON_REPLACE` and `JSON_SET` in the same query

Comment: @SalmanA, I understood what you mean now. Just changing the `JSON_REPLACE` to `JSON_SET` did the trick. Please, post this comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted. Thanks

Comment: @juan would you do the honors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_SET`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-set) instead of `JSON_REPLACE`, it will insert the key if it doesn't exist or update an existing one:

```sql
SELECT JSON_SET('{}', '$.title', 'new title');
-- {"title": "new title"}

SELECT JSON_SET('{"title":"old title"}', '$.title', 'new title');
-- {"title": "new title"}
```